# Получить ip входящего http запроса asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Имеется проект **web api asp.net core**. К серверу пользователь обращается с помощью http запроса. Как получить строчку ip адреса пользователя в формате **33.13.29.22**

Нужна строчка на C#.

`Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();` - не подходит, тк получает **ip** адрес хостинга на котором лежит **web api** приложение, а не **ip** пользователя, который обращается к нему через **http** запрос

Comment: `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress`, если нужна строка - сделайте ToString

Comment: @Aarnihauta не сработало(

Comment: Значит читайте документацию этого самого хостинга

Comment: Все зависит от сервера и настроек. Например, если сайт использует Cloudflare, то реальные данные клиента помещаются в заголовки `CF-Connecting-IP` `X-Forwarded-For`, но там также все зависит от настроек. Поэтому, на этот вопрос, уже можете ответить только вы и ваш хостер, либо указывайте больше данных, чтоб можно было разобраться в вопросе.